# C# Winform get text of richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtext

How do I get the text of a richtextbox? I've searched for so long and I can't find an answer! Why isn't there something like `richTextBox1.getText()`?

Comment: @frostbyte read title pls

Comment: @frostbyte richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear(); Documents and Blocks and Clear() doesn't exist in winform

Comment: Okay, then try this, which is for WinForms here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750532/how-to-get-displayed-text-from-richtextbox

Comment: @frostbyte can you remove downvote and duplicate? Since you know you made a mistake (I found an answer already btw)

Comment: I did not provide the downvote. I am not at the level required for downvotes. So, can't help you there.

Comment: @frostbyte D: -2, I guess people forgot their daily coffee ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write directly `richTextBox1.Text`

Comment: okay I feel stupid now thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text().Trim();
```